# LoadError Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1.0.0'
gem 'activesupport', '4.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'railties', '4.0.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'actionpack', '4.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I run `bundle install` and `bundle update` but when I visit my app locally I get this error:

```
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. 

Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile.
```

I tried `bundle show sqlite3` and I get `/Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5` which means I do have the Gem right?

So why isn't it loading?

In my `database.yml` I have this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Try removing it from development group.

Comment: Where are are you deploying? Does your server support sqlite?

Comment: @papirtiger locally...

Comment: Sorry, didn´t read it properly. Have you tried `gem pristine sqlite3`?

Comment: yes, i tried it. nothing. still same error.

Comment: What happens when you `require "sqlite3"` in irb? And why do you have it twice in your Gemfile?

Comment: running `require "sqlite3"` returns `true` and i removed the extra copy in the Gemfile. so i have it just once now.

Comment: whats in your database.yml?

Comment: i added the contents of my `database.yml` in the main post.

Comment: Check your `Gemfile.lock` in case there is a conflicting version of sqlite3 in there.

Comment: load rails console `rails c`, then try to check sqlite3 module by entering `SQLite3` inside it, if you get the `NameError`, try to include sqlite3 module and then retry checking. Yes, and then if no, remove `Gemfile.lock` and rebundle with `bundle install`

Comment: Also, your `database.yml` is specifying `sqlite` for all 3 databases, but your `Gemfile` has `pg` for production only.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I thought I could use `sqlite3` locally and `pg` on production?

Comment: @majioa i can't `rails c` cause i get the same error. it refuses to load the console and tells me about the sqlite3 gem not loading.

Comment: Ok, do from the last step, delete `Gemfile.lock` and rebundle

Comment: @majioa nothing. no change. same error.

Comment: I guess you need to investigate it, did you run rails on mac? Try to remove all the gems from Gemfile, except `rails`, and `sqlite3`, then rebundle, and run rails console

Comment: i'd rather start the app from scratch :(. thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: You can use different databases for different environments.  If I do this though I prefer to be more explicit in the `Gemfile` by putting the relevant databases under their appropriate sections.  So in your case move the `sqlite` into the `group :development, :test do` instead of having it global.  Just remember to have your `database.yml` match this config.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this:

> Go into your Gemfile.lock file and search for the 'sqlite3' entry. You'll note it reads sqlite3 (1.3.8-x86-mingw32). Change that to sqlite3 (1.3.8-x64-mingw32) and then run the bundle install command and everything should work like normal.

from [Sqlite3 gem not loading, gem installed and specified in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577533/sqlite3-gem-not-loading-gem-installed-and-specified-in-project?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had this on OSX for a `spec/dummy` app.  Without rebuilding the gemset (just rebuilding sqlite3), it was unsuccessful.

I had to do the following to get everything built properly:

```
rvm gemset empty
brew update
brew install sqlite
bundle update
```

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. Instead, flag the questions as duplicates, and post one single *good* answer to *one* copy of the question.